# es6 Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to merge statics and prototypes of several classes in to 1 masterclass like in the example below.

Is that actually possible?
My goal is that im able to merge the statics and prototypes to do things like:

Alltogether.dosomething() 
or Alltogether.o3.myoption1

```html
// class1
class Option1 {
    constructor(properties) {
        this.o = {};
        this.o.myoption1 = properties.o.myoption1;
        this.o.myoption2 = properties.o.myoption2;
    }
    dosomething1() {
        return "o1";
    }
}

// class2
class Option2 {
    constructor(properties) {
        this.o2 = {};
        this.o2.myoption1 = properties.o2.myoption1;
        this.o2.myoption2 = properties.o2.myoption2;
    }
    dosomething2() {
        return "o2";
    }
}

// class3
class Option3 {
    constructor(properties) {
        this.o3 = {};
        this.o3.myoption1 = properties.o3.myoption1;
        this.o3.myoption2 = properties.o3.myoption2;
    }
    dosomething3() {
        return "o3";
    }
}

// now i want to create a super class with the 3 classes above
// however this doesnt work...
class Alltogether extends (Option1, Option2, Option3) {
    constructor(properties) {
        //........
    }
}

// My goal is that im able to merge the statics and prototypes to do things like
// Alltogether.dosomething()  // o2
// or Alltogether.o3.myoption1
```

Comment: The point of objects is so you don't have to define these 1,2,3 classes. Define a class Option, create instances of them (your options). AllTogether would extend Option, having a prototype method that all Options inherit.

Comment: I have only one question. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple and use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

```
class Option {
    constructor(properties) {
        this.myoption1 = properties.myoption1;
        this.myoption2 = properties.myoption2;
    }
    dosomething() {
        return "o";
    }
}

class Alltogether {
    constructor(properties) {
        this.o = new Option(properties.o)
        this.o1 = new Option(properties.o1)
        this.o2 = new Option(properties.o2)
    }
}
```

If your `dosomething`s are actually that different, you can use multiple `Option` (sub)classes. If not, you should even consider using arrays instead of three numbered properties.